# Event handler tab control with jQuery

Tags: forms, event-handling, jquery

I have a survey with many input elements, and I have a progress bar that shows how much of the survey that has been filled out/answered by having a click event on the input elements. This works fine until someone use tab control to navigate through the form. Is there a tab control event, or some other event that I can use to track this behaviour?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the event `focus` to capture when the user is tabbing around in your controls:

```
$.on("focus", "input", function() { });
```